# Docker login Error with nexus repo

Tags: docker, nexus

I have installed NEXUS in VM nexus console is accessible using `http://192.168.33.60:8081/` URL, trying to login in nexus with another VM using below command

```
docker login 192.168.33.60:8081
```

after entering user-name and password it is throwing this error

```
`Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://192.168.33.60:8081/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found`
```

can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure a Docker connector port, and it must be SSL enabled:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/SSL+and+Repository+Connector+Configuration

Note that Docker is picky about SSL certificates, if you're planning on using a self signed certificate see here:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217542177-Using-Self-Signed-Certificates-with-Nexus-Repository-Manager-and-Docker-Daemon